# what are pool and dialect in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

A simple question, as stated in the title.

[image: General structure of connection that happens in SQLAlchemy]

This is the general structure of how a connection is established in the SQLAlchemy.

But I don't understand what is this Pool and Dialect.
Could anyone help me with a simple explanation of it?

(I am new to learning SQLAlchemy, but I know DBMS)

Comment: The pool is the connection pool maintained by the engine; the dialect is the RDBMS backend that is associated with the engine, for example "postgresql" or "mysql".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Pool:**

   simply means **collection** of active **database connection objects**. Instead of creating new connections objects that is costly operation, we mostly reuse already created connection objects in pool, to send queries to database.
2. **Dialect:**

   Actually Sqlalchemy makes it possible for your code to communicate with multiple databases (like Postgres,Mysql,MS,Oracal etc.).Dialect is like a personal secretary to Sqlalchemy that makes Sqlalchemy aware of specific database it has to communicate with.